# Gibt es "unoffiziell" offiziell?

Tags: duden

Sieht aus wie ein Anglizismus - oder hat jemand eine offizielle Quelle?

Allein der Duden schweigt sicht aus,
[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unoffiziell%2C%20inoffiziell&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunoffiziell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinoffiziell%3B%2Cc0) ist schon interessanter ...

Comment: Was meinst du mit "gibt es"? Dein Link zeigt ja bereits, dass es das Wort "gibt" - es wird von kompetenten Sprecher:innen des Deutschenv verwendet. Willst du wissen, ob es erlaubt ist, dieses Wort zu verwenden? Siehe dazu https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Was sind denn "kompetente" Sprecherinnen und Sprecher des Deutschen? Und wo findest du diese Kompetenz in ngram?

Comment: @HalvarF Das habe ich nicht in ngram gefunden, sondern in der Korpussuche des DWDS (siehe https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=unoffiziell&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=100)

Comment: "unoffiziell" gibt es nur unoffiziell ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Negation von Adjektiven Lateinischen Ursprungs

Viele Adjektive, die offensichtlich lateinischen Ursprungs sind, folgen dem lateinischen Vorbild und bilden die Negation mit dem Präfix *in-* bzw. *im-* oder *i* und Konsonantenverdoppelung. Beispiele sind:

- *illegitim*
- *immateriell*
- *impotent*
- *impertinent*
- *indefinit*
- *indifferent*
- *indiskutabel*
- *indisponiert*
- *inkommensurabel*
- *irregulär*

Es gibt aber auch Adjektive, die lateinischen Ursprungs sind und (dennoch) mit dem Präfix *un-* gebildet werden:

- *undefiniert* (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/undefiniert)
- *unkalkulierbar*
- *unklar* (von lat. *clarus*)
- *unpräzise*
- *unprätentiös*

Es lässt sich vermuten, dass der Unterschied davon abhängt, wie stark der lateinische Ursprung wahrgenommen wird. *klar* etwa ist bereits seit mindestens dem 12. Jahrhundert im Deutschen anzutreffen (https://www.dwds.de/wb/klar), es wird wohl von Sprecher:innen des Deutschen nicht mehr besonders stark als lateinisches Lehnwort empfunden.

Eine andere Möglichkeit, den Unterschied zu erklären, könnte in der Frage liegen, ob die Negation gemeinsam mit der positiven Form aus dem Lateinischen importiert wurde, oder ob die Negation nachträglich im Deutschen gebildet wurde. Dies könnte ein Erklärungsansatz für *unkalkulierbar* und *undefiniert* sein: *kalkulierbar* geht zwar auf lateinisch *calculare* zurück, ist aber ein nach deutschen Regeln gebildetes Adjektiv (wie man am Suffix *-bar* erkennen kann), die nach lateinischem Muster gebildete Variante wäre **inkalkulabel*, von einem etwa existierenden lateinischen (?) *incalculabilis*. Die Negation konnte also nicht direkt aus dem Lateinischen übernommen werden. Ähnlich verhält es sich mit *undefiniert*.

(Ein [vergleichbares Phänomen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35547/transformation-rules-from-latin-to-spanish) gibt es im Spanischen, wo die phonetische Veränderung lateinischer Lehnworte davon abhängt, wann und auf welchem Wege (schriftlich oder mündlich) die lateinischen Worte ins Spanische gekommen sind.)

## *inoffiziell* vs. *unoffiziell*

Bei der Frage, wie stark der lateinische Ursprung wahrgenommen wird, steht *offiziell* zwischen den Fronten. Es geht zwar auf lateinisch *officialis* zurück, kommt aber – wie [*präzise*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/pr%C3%A4zise) und auch [*prätentiös*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/pr%C3%A4tenti%C3%B6s) – nicht direkt aus dem Latein ins Deutsche, sondern über das Französische. Dies ist dem Wort auch aufgrund des typisch französichen Suffixes anzusehen (ähnlich wie bei *unprätentiös*).

Für die Bildung von *unoffiziell* könnte auch das Englische Vorbild sein, [wo *unofficial* das ebenfalls existierende *inofficial* dominiert](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unofficial%2Cinofficial&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). Im Englischen könnte dies dadurch begünstigt sein, dass *official* nicht mehr als lateinisches Lehnadjektiv, sondern als Bildung zu *office* ("Amt") wahrgenommen wird.

## Anglizismus?

Ob die Bildung von *unoffiziell* unter dem Einfluss von engl. *unofficial* steht, ist schwer zu sagen. Es scheint unplausibel, den Einfluss des Englischen rundheraus auszuschließen. Wie stark der Einfluss des Englischen ist, lässt sich aber schwer quantifizieren oder belegen.

## Semantische Unterschiede?

<sup>Für diesen Abschnitt habe ich leider keine Belege, weil sie schwer zu bekommen sind. Ich biete hier nur Arbeitshypothesen an, die sich auf Analogien und allgemeine Gesetzmäßigkeiten stützen. Die Überprüfung dieser Hypothesen ist grundsätzlich möglich, kann aber von mir wegen des Aufwands nicht geleistet werden.</sup>

Wenn zwei verschiedene Varianten eines Wortes existieren, ist es nicht ungewöhnlich, dass sich im Lauf der Zeit verschiedene Bedeutungsnuancen oder Bedeutungen herausbilden. Mir fällt gerade leider nur ein englisches Beispiel ein: [*vanguard*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vanguard) ("militärische Vorhut", "politische Vorfeldorganisation") und [*avant-gard*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avant-garde) ("Avantgarde", "künstlerische 'Wegbereiter'", "intellektuelle Progressive"), die beide auf französisch *avant-garde* zurückgehen.

Diese Nuancierung geht häufig damit einher, dass die Verwendung der jeweiligen Worte sich zunächst auf verschiedene [sprachliche Register](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Sprachebene) aufspaltet. Bei Lehnworten ist die dem Ursprung ähnlichere Form in der Regel eher im bildungssprachlichen Register anzutreffen; die Verwendung der Lehnform dient auch als Signal der Zugehörigkeit zu einer gebildeten Schicht. Diese soziale Funktion des Gebrauchs von Lehnworten führt mitunter auch zu [Hyperkorrekturen](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Hyperkorrektur) oder zu Schein-Lehnworten, die in der vermeintlichen Ursprungssprache gar nicht existieren oder eine andere Bedeutung haben (etwa: *Regisseur*, *Blamage*, *Trikot*, *Baiser*).

Dieses Prinzip scheint mir grundsätzlich auch auf *inoffiziell* vs. *unoffiziell* anwendbar zu sein: Im Gegensatz zu *unoffiziell* wird der lateinische Ursprung in *inoffiziell* besonders markiert. Es steht daher zu erwarten, dass es häufiger im bildungssprachlichen Bereich anzutreffen ist.

Bilden sich zwischen verschiedenen Formen semantische Unterschiede heraus, so sind die soziolinguistischen Differenzen häufig die Grundlage dafür. Das scheint mir grundsätzlich auch auf *inoffiziell* und *unoffiziell* zuzutreffen.

Eine erste Idee für die Frage, ob sich tatsächlich Bedeutungsnuancen herausgebildet haben, könnte man bekommen, wenn man die Korpussuche des DWDS studiert:

- [Treffer für unoffiziell](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=unoffiziell&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=100)
- [Treffer für *inoffiziell*](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=inoffiziell&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=100)

Die positive Form *offiziell* hat selbst zwei Bedeutungen, eine engere und eine weitere. Im engeren Sinn heißt *offiziell* "von einer amtlichen Stelle, Regierung oder Behörde ausgehend", "dienstlich". Im weiteren Sinn hat es die Bedeutung "feierlich", "förmlich". Ich würde vermuten, dass *inoffiziell* eher als Verneinung der ersten Bedeutung verwendet wird, und *unoffiziell* tendenziell eher zur Verneinung der zweiten Bedeutung. Einige Fundstellen in der verlinkten Korpussuche scheinen dem zu entsprechen:

> Der festliche Akt verlief, wie es sich bei Flechtheim gebührt, höchst unoffiziell. [Vossische Zeitung (Morgen-Ausgabe), 03.04.1928]

> Und doch haben mir die Beweise unoffizieller, aufrichtiger Herzensteilnahme von so vielen edeln, guten Menschen in diesen Tagen unsagbar wohlgetan. [Suttner, Bertha von: Autobiographie. In: Deutsche Literatur von Frauen, Berlin: Directmedia Publ. 2001 [1909], S. 70574]

Andererseits gibt es auch viele Treffer, an denen *unoffiziell* als Gegenteil von *offiziell* im engeren Sinne verwendet wird. Das Korpus scheint insgesamt zu klein zu sein, um hier zu belastbaren Aussagen zu kommen. Insbesondere fällt auf, dass etliche Treffer für *unoffiziell* aus *Die Wirtschaftsethik der Weltreligionen* von Max Weber stammen.

Ein besserer Ansatz, um einer eventuellen Bedeutungsdifferenzierung auf die Spur zu kommen, wäre eine [Kollokations-Analyse](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Kollokation), bei der man die Worte bestimmt, die im näheren Umfeld der beiden Adjektive wahrscheinlich anzutreffen sind. Fände man hier statistische signifikante Unterschiede, würde das für eine stattgehabte Bedeutungsdifferenzierung sprechen. Obwohl das eine sehr interessante Analyse wäre, habe ich leider keine Zeit, sie zu leisten.

Answer (score 6):

> Auf das Lateinische zurückgehende Adjektive, die mit einem Vokal beginnen, werden 'ganz offiziell' (1) mit dem Präfix "in" negiert.

[Inoffiziell](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/inoffiziell) auf duden.de

(1) Da es, wie der [Link](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen) zu normativen Fragen schön aufzeigt, keine verbindliche Norm des Deutschen, sondern lediglich deskriptive Evidenzen gibt, ist 'ganz offiziell' humoristisch zu verstehen; kompetenter Sprecher oder kompetente Sprecherin kann man jedenfalls auch ohne Lateinkenntnisse werden und sein.

> Auf das Lateinische zurückgehende Adjektive, die mit einem Konsonanten beginnen, werden mit dem Präfix "i_" negiert, wobei _ den anlautenden Konsonanten assimiliert.

Illegitim, immateriell, irregulär.

> Eine Ausnahme dazu bilden anlautende bilabiale Plosive, [b] und [p]; hier wird aus dem alveolaren [n] in "in" ein bilabiales [m].

Imbezil, impertinent, impotent.

> Ausserdem kann das [n] vor gutturalen Anlauten ganz verschwinden.

Ignorant.

---

Zusatz 1: Dass sich der Gebrauch der negiernden Vorsilbe "un" ausbreitet und mittlerweile gar als 'auch richtig' gilt, muss mit Verweis auf die 'Sprache als sich dynamisch den Sprechenden anpassend' wohl oder übel hingenommen werden; was auch immer das dann über die Sprechenden aussagt... Normative Gültigkeit kann "un" aber kaum unterstellt werden.

Zusatz 2: Das Präfix "non" negiert in einigen Fällen auch Adjektive lateinischen Ursprungs.

nonkonform, nonverbal.

Zusatz 3: Der Kommentar (cit.): "Es scheint ... eher darauf anzukommen, ob das Adjektiv als lateinischen Ursprungs wahrgenommen wird." ist klug und nötigt mir weitere Recherche ab; in lateinischer Grammatik gilt die hier beschriebene Regel, über deren generelle Gültigkeit im (Mh.-)Deutschen muss ich erst nachfragen; sonst bleibt das inklar ;)

Comment: Hi Starrin! Mit "ganz offiziell" meinst du wahrscheinlich, dass das eine Regel ist. Kannst du genauer eingrenzen, welchen Geltungsbereich diese Regel hat, bzw. wer sie aufstellt? Das würde die Antwort verbessern. Der in der Frage angegebene Link zeigt ja schonmal, dass _unoffiziell_ tatsächlich verwendet wird. Siehe auch: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/normative-fragen

Comment: Es gibt jedenfalls auch Gegenbeispiele, zum Beispiel _unklar_. Und schließlich ist die Frage, ob offiziell überhaupt aus dem Latein ins Deutsche gekommen ist. Die  Endung lässt eher vermuten, dass es über das Französische gekommen ist. https://www.dwds.de/wb/offiziell bestätigt das. Es scheint für die Frage _un-_ oder _in-_  also eher darauf anzukommen, ob das Adjektiv als lateinischen Ursprungs wahrgenommen wird.

Comment: Mit 'ganz offiziell' sollte eine Keule geschwungen werden; habe das - auch im Zusammenhang mit dem übrigen Kommentar - etwas ausgedeutscht. Der Metathread ist lesenswert, besten Dank; und selbiges für den Hinweis des Empfindens.

Comment: +1 eine lesenswerte Antwort ist es (selbst) ohne Frage.

Comment: Wenn *unoffiziell* (statt *inoffiziell*) deiner Meinung nach  "verboten" ist, ist dann *halbofiziell* (z.B. als Eigenschaft von Quellen) auch verboten? Oder noch ein anderer Aspekt: Wenn wir die Negation aus der Ursprungssprache eines Wortes übernehmen sollen, sollten wir dann nicht besser auch gleich die anderen Formbildungen von z.B. Adjektiven (wie Substantivierung, Steigerung,...) auch aus der Ursprungssprache übernehmen? Ich glaube, du gehst hier mit der Sprachentwicklung ein bißchen zu hart ins Gericht.

Comment: Ich bin einverstanden damit, dass sich die Sprache wandelt, gell. Bist du einverstanden damit, dass sie das bisweilen deshalb tut, weil eine Vielzahl ihrer Sprecherinnen und Sprecher mal unverständig, mal sprachfaul ist? * Die Negation über 'in' brauchen wir nicht übernehmen, das haben wir schon längst. Davon wegzukommen, steht uns offen, weitere Übernahmen aber genauso. * Es wurde argumentiert, 'unoffiziell' könne ein Anglizismus sein: eine Übernahme dann von Dritten. Meine Haltung dazu: Ursprünge sind zum Kennen da! Und in dieser sind wir uns doch einig?

Comment: "sprachfaul" ist so negativ. Wenn du geschrieben hättest, dass sich Sprache hauptsächlich zur Effizienzverbesserung weiterentwickelt, wäre ich mit dir einig (und ja,  ein Haupttreiber für Effizienz ist nunmal Faulheit).

Answer (score 1):

Einen Anglizismus vermag ich hier nicht erkennen; man kann das Wort bilden, es entspricht einer der normalen Methoden wie ich ein deutsches Adjektiv negiere.

In diesem konkreten Fall ist 'offiziell' aber lateinischen Ursprungs, sodass sich hier die entsprechend lateinische Vorsilbe für die Verneinung erhalten hat: 'inoffiziell'.

Siehe auch https://epub.uni-regensburg.de/41419/1/RPiL%2015_Schneider.pdf Kapitel 5.2 und insbesondere 5.2.1 und 5.2.2.